# When alert() is removed, code behaves strange

Tags: javascript, html

Helo,

I am building a search box that will offer choices and use arrows to navigate. It works nice with alert(), but if alert is removed, it highlight (=change background property) and then dehightlight. When in debugger, it works fine. I suspect too many event captures.
What is the problem.

alert must be in this function:

```
function ChangeCurrentCell() 
{   
        //alert('Row' + currentRow);
        var tableID = document.getElementById("seach_table");
        var tableRow = tableID.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var cellToLight;

        //checking rows
        total_rows = tableRow.length;
        //alert('Total'+total_rows);
        if (currentRow<0)
        {
            currentRow=0;
        }
        if (currentRow>=total_rows)
        {
            currentRow=total_rows-1;
        }
        // clear everything
        for (var i=0; i < total_rows; i++)
        {
            tableRow = tableID.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
            cellToLight = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            tableRow.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
        }

        //hightlight required
        tableID = document.getElementById("seach_table");
        tableRow = tableID.getElementsByTagName("tr")[currentRow];
        cellToLight = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        tableRow.style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type='edit' id='text_to_search' name='text_to_search' autocomplete="off" value='' 
                                    size='25' onkeyup='return update_search_offer(event);' onkeypress="return check_for_enter_code(event);" onkeydown="return navigate(event);">
```

Full JavaScript:

```
function update_search_offer(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 27)
    {
        //alert('Hide');
        document.getElementById("text_offer").style.visibility='hidden';

    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("text_offer").style.visibility='visible';   
        if (document.getElementById("text_to_search").value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("text_offer").style.display = "none";

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("text_offer").style.display = "block";
            var word_search = ""+document.getElementById("text_to_search").value;
            $.post("_lookup.php", { query: word_search }).done(function(data) {

                        document.getElementById("seach_table").innerHTML = data;
                        if (data == '')
                        {
                            document.getElementById("text_offer").style.display = "none";
                        }
                });
        }
    }
}

function offer_selected(selection)
{
    document.getElementById("text_to_search").value =selection; 
    document.getElementById("search_button").click();
}

function check_for_enter_code(e)
{
    //alert('Call');
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("text_to_search").value == '')
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

var currentRow = 0;
var total_rows=0;
function ChangeCurrentCell() 
{   
        //alert('Row' + currentRow);
        var tableID = document.getElementById("seach_table");
        var tableRow = tableID.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var cellToLight;

        //checking rows
        total_rows = tableRow.length;
        //alert('Total'+total_rows);
        if (currentRow<0)
        {
            currentRow=0;
        }
        if (currentRow>=total_rows)
        {
            currentRow=total_rows-1;
        }
        // clear everything
        for (var i=0; i < total_rows; i++)
        {
            tableRow = tableID.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
            cellToLight = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            tableRow.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
        }

        //hightlight required
        tableID = document.getElementById("seach_table");
        tableRow = tableID.getElementsByTagName("tr")[currentRow];
        cellToLight = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        tableRow.style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";
    }

function navigate(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 38) //up arrow
    {
        currentRow--;
        ChangeCurrentCell();
        return false;
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 40) //40 - down arrow
    {
        currentRow++;
        ChangeCurrentCell();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Function desciptions: update_search_offer - perform AJAX query, and look for possible opions. If ESC key is pressed than it close offers box. 
check_for_enter_code - if Enter is pressed perform search

Comment: I checked - same in Firefox. (I code with Chrome)

Comment: Please indicate which `alert` you think is the issue. Tip: Use `console.log` instead of `alert` to debug your code, since `console.log` won't stop execution

Comment: It looks like it disaapeared when key is released.

Comment: Any alert in function ChangeCurrentCell()  WORKS! Consle.log does Not.

Comment: I think that the problem is in AJAX method that it update table structure. In alert case, it is performed before hightlighning.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The problem was in AJAX method that was called every time and updated the table.
I added to function update_search_offer() next code:

```
else if ((event.keyCode == 38) || (event.keyCode == 40))
    {
        // do nothing
    }
```

So it do not update field, if up or down is pressed. Sorry, that bothered you.